# how to select only those brands which don't have status = true in any of the products

Tags: postgresql

Query is

```
select brand
from products
where status = false
and brand not in (
  select brand
  from products
  where status = true
  group by brand
)
group by brand;
```

Basically, i want to select only those brands which don't have status = true in any of the products.

I want to optimize the above query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the boolean aggregate function [`bool_or()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html):

```
select brand
from products
group by brand
having not bool_or(status);
```

Comment: +1. I was looking for this function, hadn't used it before but figured PostgreSQL would have it.  Interestingly, you could use `not bool_or()` or `bool_and()` with the same results, though the OP might want to consider whether the column `status` is nullable or not and adjust accordingly.

Comment: The query works with nullable column as well. Alternatively one could use `bool_and(not status)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the boolean values to bit using a `CASE` statement, then `MAX` on that:

```
SELECT brand
FROM products
GROUP BY brand
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN status = TRUE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
```